# Magento 2 get shipped items in sales_order_shipment_save_after event

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, shipment, items

I want the items that are shipped in the "sales_order_shipment_save_after" event(Not all the ordered items,only the currently shipped items). How can I do it. Here is my code. This code gives shipment id, but the shipment items are not returned.

```
class ProcessShipment implements ObserverInterface
{


     /**
     * @var eventManager
     */
    protected $_eventManager;

    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_shipmentItemCollectionFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Manager $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Item\CollectionFactory $shipmentItemCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager       
    ) {
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;  
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
           }



    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {       

        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        $items = $this->_shipmentItemCollectionFactory->create()->setShipmentFilter($shipment->getId());

        foreach($items as $item){    
            $id = $item->getProductId();    
        }

}
```

Comment: The shipment model has a `getAllItems` method returning an array of items. Could that be what you want?

Comment: But it returns all the ordered items

Comment: @JancyAbraham how did you acheive these plz let me know

Answer (score 4):

```
class ProcessShipment implements ObserverInterface
{


     /**
     * @var eventManager
     */
    protected $_eventManager;

    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_shipmentItemCollectionFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Manager $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Item\CollectionFactory $shipmentItemCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager       
    ) {
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;  
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
           }



    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {       

        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();

        foreach ($shipment->getItemsCollection() as $item) {    
            $id = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductId();    
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: $shipment->getItemsCollection() returns all the ordered items. If I do a partial shipment,this returns the all  ordered items.

Comment: Please refer \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment. If you have instance of this than getItemsCollection method will return items connected with that shipment only.

Comment: @ChandreshP., how to get shipment Id here? i used this $shipment->getId(); but not working