# magento 2 sales_order_shipment_save_after does not fire

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I created an observer for **changing the shipping method amount** but it does not work.
This is my code

> **`Cop/Postexpres/etc/events.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
    <observer name="popopp" instance="Cop\Postexpres\Model\Observer"  />
</event>
```

and

> **`Cop/Postexpres/Model/Observer.php`**

```
 namespace Cop\Postexpres\Observer;
      use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
       var_dump($order->getData());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you passed wrong instance in your `events.xml`. You passed

```
<observer name="popopp" instance="Cop\Postexpres\Model\Observer"  />
```

and your namespace `Observer` is

```
namespace Cop\Postexpres\Observer;
```

So, you just need to add correct namespace(you are missing `Model` in your namespace).

Comment: oh sorry ... i was wrong about copy ... but in my code all namesapace and instance are true ...i was check it for  sevral time

Comment: Post your correct code here so peoples don't add as answer :)

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.ir/ucln
https://paste.ubuntu.ir/fmgd
app/code/Netweb/Postexpres/etc/events.xml
app/code/Netweb/Postexpres/Model/Observer.php

Comment: And please also post your observer code @ghdarvishani

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.ir/ucln ... i already add observer code

Comment: Please try to change class name with valid name and do not try `die()` in observer try to put some log file.

Comment: For temp log you can use this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92441/2589 it is very easy to debug

Comment: Thanks ... i do all but my observer does not fire

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71993/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-gh-darvishani).

Comment: i install fresh magento and test is but does not worked ... 
and create new event
 <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="custom_payment" instance="Netweb\Postexpres\Model\Shipment" />
    </event>
it is worked .... observer class worked but when i change event name to sales_order_shipment_save_before it does not worked
i think the sales_order_shipment_save_before is removed from magento

Comment: can you shared your code

Comment: Do you know when this(`sales_order_shipment_save_after `) event fire?

Comment: i think when shipment list are loaded ...am i wrong

Comment: No :) This event is generated When the shipment is saved. For example (Open any placed order from backend then click on `Ship` from header section then it will redirect into new page after that do page scroll then you can see `Submit Shipment` button just click on this and wait after generating shipment you can see new entry in your log file)

Comment: Oops :( ... i want change shipment amount on checkout

Comment: ahhhhh big gape :) btw you can accept the answer if my guideline helps you @ghdarvishani

Comment: ok ...i do it but just tell me which event i should used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72034/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-gh-darvishani).

Comment: @KeyurShah, yes its working fine, but I am trying to get source_code from shipment_Id, from the table inventory_shipment_source, which is not present in the table at this time, any suggestion please..

Answer (score 2):

**Try following code:**

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_shipment_save_after" instance="
            [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Observer\ProcessShipment" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Observer/ProcessShipment.php

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProcessShipment implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .... i copy you code and replace company and module name ... and compile and flush cache ... but it doesn't worked

Comment: @ghdarvishani - Maybe event "sales_order_shipment_save_after" is not available in M2.

Comment: omg :( ... how i can check it ... i found this event after many search

Comment: You can check using command: **find . -type f -exec grep -n -H -A 2 -T "eventManager->dispatch(" {} \;**

Comment: i think you are right ...but which event fire for change shipment amount ?!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156932/magento-2-get-shipped-items-in-sales-order-shipment-save-after-event
on this question sales_order_shipment_save_after has been used

Comment: I can confirm that `sales_order_shipment_save_after` event is available in M2. I tested it and it works without any problem. @PratikOza

Comment: @KeyurShah - Thanks for this info. Keep helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Your namespace is incorrect. In your observer class, namespace should be

> Cop\Postexpres\Model\Observer

instead of

> Cop\Postexpres\Observer

Rest everything is fine!